# Very slow SQL ORDER BY, and EXPLAIN doesn't explain

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mariadb

The query:

```
SELECT
    m.*,
    mic.*
FROM
    members m,
    members_in_class_activities mic
WHERE
    m.id = mic.member_id AND
    mic.not_cancelled = '1' AND
    mic.class_activity_id = '32' AND
    mic.date = '2016-02-14' AND
    mic.time = '11:00:00'
ORDER BY
    mic.reservation_order
```

Table `members` has ~ 100k records, and table `members_in_class_activities` has about 300k. The result set is just 2 records. (Not 2k, just 2.)

All relevant columns are indexed (`id` and `reservation_order` are primary): `member_id, not_cancelled, class_activity_id, date, time`.

There is *also* a UNIQUE key for `class_activity_id + member_id + date + time + not_cancelled`. `not_cancelled` is `NULL` or `'1'`.

All other queries are very fast (1-5 ms), but this one is crazy slow: 600-1000 ms.

**What doesn't help:**

- select only the 2 primary keys instead of `*` (0 % change)
- a real `JOIN` instead of an implicit join (it actually seems slightly slower, but probably not) (0 % change)
- removing the join to `members` entirely makes it *slightly* faster (15 % change)

**What does help, immensely:**

- remove the ORDER BY on the primary key (99% change)

I have only 2 questions:

1. What????
2. How do I still `ORDER BY x`, but make it fast too? Do I really need a separate column?

I'm running `10.1.9-MariaDB` on my dev machine, but it's slow on production's MySQL `5.5.27-log` too.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  A guess -- you are mixing `VARCHARs` and numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use order by on your main query. Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM (   
  ... your query
) ORDER BY mic.reservation_order
```

As you mentioned that `members_in_class_activities has about 300k` records, so your order by will apply on all **300k** records that definitely slow down your query.

Comment: It orders first, and then conditions? That's weird... Many other queries run on much bigger tables and they order just fine. My DBAL doesn't do sub queries well, so I'll have to try it later. I'm very disappointed in MySQL if this is really it.

Comment: On 2 other queries (on this and another much bigger table), it makes it much slower. They both have an ORDER on the biggest table too.

Comment: So you are saying your query still takes `600-1000 ms`?

Comment: No, that one is fast like this, but I tried it on 2 other slow-ish queries with sorting on the big table, and they're slower like this. Since EXPLAIN can't explain, maybe you can. Same type deal, but much bigger dataset (~5 M records). Result is only 20 rows, but 'your way' makes it slower.

Comment: Can you please post your queries? I'm not a sql expert but will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

`class_activity_id + member_id + date + time + not_cancelled` -- not optimal.

Start with the '=' fields in the `WHERE` in any order, then add on the `ORDER BY` field:

```
INDEX(class_activity_id, date, time, not_cancelled,
      reservation_order)
```

Since you seem to need the `UNIQUE` constraint, then it would be almost as good to shuffle your index by putting `member_id` at the end (where it will be 'out of the way', but not used):

```
UNIQUE(class_activity_id, date, time, not_cancelled, member_id)
```

In general, it is bad to split a `date` and `time` apart; suggest a `DATETIME` column for the pair.

[Cookbook on creating indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: Indexing wasn't the problem. The order was. Query takes 2ms without the order. Combined index is a good idea. Link goes on the todo list.

Comment: Yes, I'm mixing int and string. Is that bad? Most tables have ints and strings... Or do you mean inside the index?

Comment: `JOIN ... ON int_column = varchar_column` or `varchar_column = 1234`

Comment: Ooh. No. But I do always do `int_column = '1234'`, with quotes. The only column-to-column comparison is `m.id = mic.member_id` and they are identical (as innodb demands).

Comment: OK, maybe that is not the cause of the trouble.